# REST API, when to use @PathParam, @QueryParam, @RequestBody, and/or @RequestHeader

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, restful-architecture

I have been trying to find an answer if there is some sort of standard in regards to when/when not to use the above methods of passing information to a REST call.

I have been looking everywhere but every post only talks about the difference between 2 of the listed methods, or 3, not all 4.

Comment: Before worrying about those annotation you have to understand how REST API works in general. Such what is the different between URL path and query parameter and sending POST/PUT body vs GET methods. The annotations just allow you to get those values already mapped to POJOs in your Spring controller.

Comment: @tsolakp I understand the difference between POST, PUT, GET, HEAD, DELETE, etc. methods. I understand how REST APIs work, and the above annotations. All I am asking is what the "standard" is for sending data to the REST API call. For example, if I am sending a parameter, how should I do so? Why and why should I not just put it in the Header? Like, X : 0, Y : 2, etc. Why should/should I not just send it as a JSON object in the request body like { "x" : 0, "y" : 2 }? Why should/should I not make it part of the path like /rest/path/x/0/y/2 (obviously bad but just example) or /rest/path/?x=0&y=2

Comment: That's my point. Those questions have nothing to do with annotations they are more of towards REST best practices.

Comment: Isn't that what my question said? Just because I have an @infront of it (which I understand means it is an annotation) doesn't necessarily mean that I am asking about the annotation. In fact, if you read the full question, I never once ask about the annotations themselves, just where it is best to use them, i.e. REST best practices.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1. @PathParam**

PathParam is generally used to get to a Resource using it's `id`.
Eg. `/employees/{emp_id}`

Usually it's a HTTP response code 404 if you don't find an Resource by it's `id` as `path param`.

**2. @QueryParam**

`QueryParam` is generally used to get to an entity using any other field than it's id. Think of "search" or "filter" rather than using "id" to reach the entity. In this case, you will have to expect an array of entities as the response unlike the single entity that you will get as the response for sending `id` as `pathParam`

Ex. `/employees?firstname=joe`

Note: `QueryParam` can be used for other operations too, such as `sort`. Eg. `/departments/123/employees?sort_by=salary`

Usually it's an http response code 200 with an empty array as the response body, if you don't find any entities by the search parameter(s) or filter parameter(s).

**3. @RequestBody**

Usually it's a POST, PUT or PATCH http verb with which we will send the requestbody.

[Why it's a bad idea to send requestbody with http GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

[Why it's a bad idea to send requestbody with http DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request)

Following are the situations where we use RequestBody

**A. State Mutation**

To achieve state mutation, usually json/xml representation of entity's desired state will be sent as `requestBody` with POST/PUT/PATCH verb. Rest principles doesn't say anything about json or xml, it can be anything; it can be compressed binary formats such as protobuf, avro, cap'n'proto, flatbuffers etc or even plain text too.

**B. READ operations (These are examples where READ doesn't equate to HTTP GET**)

- a. **To avoid Loooong Urls** - If the parameters required to GET an
  entity is way too long, we will usually use request body to send it,
  rather than using url. Http Protocol or Rest principles doesn't limit
  you on the url size, however some browsers have limit on max length
  of the url.

  [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

  b. **graphql** - Here you will be POSTing the query using requestbody
  to fetch the data in your desired format

  c. **Security reason** - If you have to send confidential data like
  password/tokens to fetch some data, usually you will have to post it
  in either request body or in headers. (Why? because, if it's in url,
  there is a high possibility that it may end up in application logs)

**4. @RequestHeader**

Generally used for sending metadata; Not the actual entity body (data). Eg. request-correlation-id, authheader, security tokens etc

**5. @Matrixparam, @CookieParam etc**

There are other not-so popular HTTP verbs like [@Matrixparam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183875/whats-the-difference-between-queryparam-and-matrixparam-in-jax-rs) and @CookieParam are out there in the JAX-RS spec. This is the [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html) (Keep in mind that Jersey is reference implementation of JAX-RS. You may not find equivalent thing in Spring)

### Other interesting & related reads

[When to use @QueryParam vs @PathParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552248/when-to-use-queryparam-vs-pathparam)

[What is the difference between @PathParam and @QueryParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579744/what-is-the-difference-between-pathparam-and-queryparam)

[HTTP POST with URL query parameters -- good idea or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611906/http-post-with-url-query-parameters-good-idea-or-not)

[How do I POST JSON data with cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-to-post-json-data-with-curl-from-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-rest)

Comment: For completeness you might also want to add `@MatrixParam` to the list