# @PathParam Vs @QueryParam vs @MatrixParam

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am newbie in RESTful jersey. 
I would like to ask what is the different among '@PathParam' Vs '@QueryParam' vs '@MatrixParam' in jersey?.

Comment: For an explanation about @MatrixParam, I liked this analogy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46565703/3154883

Answer (score 0):

Can't help you with the @MatrixParam but can give you an answer for the other two:

- @PathParam: you use placeholder in the path. For example: @Path("/demo/{id}"). In this case the {id} part is your placeholde which you get with @PathParam("id")
- @QueryParam: you use the normal uri query Syntax. For example: google.com?q=searchquery which translates to: @QueryParam("q") in your application