# REST API Design with Composite ID

Tags: rest, http

What is the best way to design a RESTful resource for an object with a composite id? For example, suppose I have a `GET /people` resource for getting a list of person records. A person doesn't have a single id; instead, it is identified by firstName, lastName, and birthdate. How should I design the resource to get a single person?

Comment: By the way, although its very rare, two person with the same name, can have the same bithday. So this is quite a poor choice for a PK.

Comment: This is a hypothetical example. Please operate under the assumption that firstName, lastName, and birthdate guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: I agree with @jwzirilli - you should use a mechanism that (almost) guarantees the uniqueness of a person. The social security number f.e. would be such a number for persons. If in your system a combination of `firstName`, `lastName` and `birthday` is guaranteed to create a unique identifier, you could also use a [matrix-parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048121/url-matrix-parameters-vs-request-parameters): `GET /people;firstName=John;lastName=Smith;birthday=1973-12-01`

Answer (score 5):

I would use one of the following variations:

```
GET /people/John/Smith/1973-12-01
```

or

```
GET /people/John,Smith,1973-12-01
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272383/rest-api-design-with-composite-id/49277183#comment50541276_31272383), if you don't have a single identifier that ensure uniqueness, you could consider *matrix variables*:

```
GET /people;firstname=John;lastname=Smith;birthday=1973-12-01
```

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
GET /people/firstName/X/lastName/Y/birthdate/AAAA-MM-DD
```