# REST - How to set variable equal to POST URL Parameter?

Tags: java, rest, csv, export-to-csv

Still super new to REST, but close to finishing my first program.

I am attempting to create a CSV with the value of the POST URL Parameter being passed into it each time I POST.

Is there a way of setting my variable to be equal to my POST URL Parameter?

Code below (value is temporarily set to 10 while I figure this out):

```
@Path("/values")
public class values {

int totalSum = 0;

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public int getSum() throws IOException {
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
    List<String[]> read = reader.readAll();
    return sum.sum(read, totalSum);
}

@POST
public String addValue() throws IOException {
    int value = 10;
    String valueString = Integer.toString(value);
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv", true), ',');
    String[] entries = valueString.split(",");
    writer.writeNext(entries);
    writer.close();
    return "ok";  
}  

@DELETE
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String deleteList() throws IOException {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("yourfile.csv", false); 
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw, false);
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    fw.close();
    return "ok";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now you need the base url, and when you add /{some_value} it gets mapped via `PathVariable` to String value `test`

Like so?

```
@Path("/{test}")
@POST
// Javax.ws.rs.PathParam
public String addValue(@PathParam("test") final String test) throws 
// SpringFramework
//public String addValue(@PathVariable("test") final String test) throws IOException {
    final String value = test;
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(value, true), ',');
    String[] entries = valueString.split(",");
    writer.writeNext(entries);
    writer.close();
    return "ok";  
}
```

See [link](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-pathparam-example/) for more information

Comment: Appreciate your response and apologies if I am being dense, but how would I resolve this error? http://puu.sh/jxzv2/85628b1438.png - Thanks!

Comment: Or are you indicating that I create a new class?

Comment: Import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable I am presuming you are using springframework. Otherwise (see updated answer), use PathParam

Comment: I'm not using springframework. Should I look at importing it into my project or do any other alternatives exist?

Comment: Can you change it in @PathParam? I don't think you can use the @PathVariable if the rest of your REST is not Spring...

Comment: It works perfectly! If I had to have the variable being passed in be an integer, what would change in the Syntax?

Comment: Change the type from `String` to `int`, so `@PathParam("test") final int test`

Comment: Great. Is it required that @Path be ("EXAMPLE/{value}") or is there a way to have it be where you can type EXAMPLE?value=10?

Comment: For that, it would be better to redirect you to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048121/url-matrix-parameters-vs-request-parameters . Url matrix parameter are a bit different...