# Spring HATEOAS Link with Matrix Variable Not Working

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I am trying to generate and add a link to a RESTful resource from a Spring MVC controller. Our API requires the use of HTTP matrix variables. Unfortunately, the self link generated is missing the matrix variable from the URI.

```
@BasePathAwareController
@RequestMapping("/licenses")
public class LicenseController {

  @Autowired
  private LicenseRepository repository;

  @RequestMapping(path = "/{licenseId}/violations", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @RestResource(rel = "violations")
  @ResponseBody
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public ResponseEntity<?> getViolations(@PathVariable String licenseId, @MatrixVariable(name = "state") String state) {
    try {
      StateContextHolder.setState(state);
      List<ViolationEntity> violations = repository.findOne(licenseId).getViolations();

      if (violations == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Resources<?>>(HttpStatus.OK);
      }
      else {
        Resources<?> entityResource = new Resources(violations);
        entityResource.add(linkTo(methodOn(LicenseController.class).getViolations(licenseId, state)).withSelfRel());

        return new ResponseEntity<Resources<?>>(entityResource, HttpStatus.OK);
      }
    }
    finally {
      StateContextHolder.clear();
    }

  }
}
```

For the HTTP GET /licenses/123456789;state=NY/violations, the returned self link is missing the state matrix parameter:

```
{
  ...,
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/licenses/123456789/violations"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't want to hardcode this in, so I am trying to figure out how to do this with the Spring HATEOAS or Spring Data REST APIs.

I need to use matrix parameters in order to refine the licenses path element. You can read more about why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048121/url-matrix-parameters-vs-request-parameters). Suffice it to say, there is some custom behavior we are doing prior to Spring Data retrieving the entities from the repository.

Comment: _"I need to use matrix parameters in order to refine the licenses path element"_ - Assuming there is a license resource and license IDs are not unique across the states then `123456789;state=NY` as a whole is a key. There is no refinement. FWIW you can try `/{licenseId};state={state}/violations` with `state` being a path variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it Spring HATEOAS has no support for matrix parameters at this time.

1. See this part of the [UriTemplate](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/UriTemplate.java#L288). It uses different variable types to build the Uri. A matrix parameter isn't one of them.
2. See the [VariableType](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/TemplateVariable.java#L203) enum, which was used to do the switch on. There is also no matrix param.

Comment: I opened [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/437) within the Spring HATEOS project.