# Angular 1 component router query params

Tags: angularjs, angular-component-router

I'm using angular 1 with new component router. 
I have $routeConfig like this:

```
{ path: '/list', name: 'ListCmp', component: 'listCmp', useAsDefault: true }
```

I want to navigate to this component with custom query params.

```
$router.navigate(['ListCmp', {itemId: 1, name: 'prop1'}]);
```

After navigating I get this Url: **localhost/list;name=1;prop1**
The problem is what I have a lot of places where I use **$location.search()**, but this method can't parse url with semicolon separated values. How can I make this new router to generate old style query params like:

**localhost/list?name=1&prop1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `ListCmp` is a child route of another component, parameters will be generated in the matrix format, not the query format. You can read more about matrix params vs query params [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048121/url-matrix-parameters-vs-request-parameters).

What it essentially means "is that matrix parameters apply to a particular path element while query parameters apply to the request as a whole".

Regarding your problem, do you have to use `$location.search()`? You can use the `$routerOnActivate` lifecycle hook and access the parameters there within your `ListCmp`.