# Understanding Route Parameters in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular 2. I was going through 
[this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html) link ,
which mentions different ways of writing route links.

```
1. <a [routerLink]="[ '/path', routeParam ]">
2. <a [routerLink]="[ '/path', { matrixParam: 'value' } ]">
3. <a [routerLink]="[ '/path' ]" [queryParams]="{ page: 1 }">
4. <a [routerLink]="[ '/path' ]" fragment="anchor">
```

I am only aware of the 1st type of route , can anyone explain about
the other three

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The first is part of the path. This are route parameters

```
{ path: '/path/:someParam', ...
```

3) are query parameters that are added after the path (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

```
/path/xxx?queryParam=value
```

2) are [matrix parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048121/url-matrix-parameters-vs-request-parameters) and similar to 3) but query parameters can only be used at top-level routes and matrix parameters 2) can only be used on child routes

```
/path/child/;page=1/otherchild?queryParam=value
```

4) Is the HTML [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) part

```
/path/xxx?queryParam=value#anchor
```

which makes the browser scroll to an `<a name="anchor">` or an element with the id `anchor` `<header id="anchor">`. (The fragment identifier is only processed by the client (browser) and never sent to the server)