# Angular 2 difference between route parameters style

Tags: angular, angular2-router3, angular2-router

If I navigate programmatically using Router's `navigate` method

`this.router.navigate(['/articles', {id: 1}]);` result url is `/articles;page=1`

and the second way

`this.router.navigate(['/articles', id]);` result url is `/articles/1`

In both variant I can get values via `this.activatedRoute.params.forEach((params: Params) => {});`

So what is the difference except style?

P.S. Found [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048121/url-matrix-parameters-vs-request-parameters) related to differences between query params & matrix params

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{id: 1}` in `['/articles', {id: 1}]` is an optional route parameters and added as matrix parameters to child routes and query parameters to the root route

`['/articles', id]` is a normal and required route parameter that replaces `:id` in the route path.

Comment: Thx for clearfication, but what is the best choice for setting optional parameter like page number: /articles?page=1 or /articles;page=1 ?

Comment: That depends on what you want to accomplish. `:id` is used for route matching. Query and matrix parameters just pass values along while not being considered for route matching. It also depends if you want `/articles` to be a valid route or only `/articles/someid`.

Comment: Actually `/article;page=1` is invalid. There is a change coming to make this an error. As mentioned optional route parameters on the root route are serialized as query parameters, therefore only the former is valid. `/parent/child;someparam=somevalue?page=1` would be valid because `someparam` is a parameter on a child route. I don't know how that behaves when you have an empty path root route and `article` is the child route. In this case your 2nd example might be valid. Had to test to know what the resulting behavior would be.