# Some strange index in angular 2 route

Tags: angular, routes

I'm trying to get the url for some component.

Firstly I'm trying to get URL tree by calling:

```
router.createUrlTree(['Dashboard'])
```

After that I'm calling `toString` method to get url for calling the component, but I get following string:

```
"/pages;0=Dashboard"
```

I don't understand where does `;0=` part come from? What is it? Anybody have explanation?

I defined pages route and dashboard as child of the pages route.

Comment: It's a matrix parameter, which mean it's a query parameter of a child route.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Intersting, looks like an inner representation. I really expected to see just a normal human readable url.

Comment: That's a normal readable URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048121/url-matrix-parameters-vs-request-parameters

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Got it. Does it mean route.toString() by default use matrix parameters form? Are there are any way to get request parameters form from the route?

Comment: As mentioned in my first comment, matrix parameters are query parameters added to child routes. If query parameters are added to the root root, they are added as `/pages?0=Dashboard`. I don't know what you are doing exactly and therefore can't tell where this parameter comes from.

Comment: Try `router.createUrlTree(['/Dashboard'])`