# RESTApi EndPoint GET Multiple Resources

Tags: rest, http, api-design

The operation bellow retrieve of all books only the ones that are into the request. It is clearly a **GET** operation.

From your perspective what is better ( pro/cons ) of doing those two bellow:

- **Note:**

> GET - api/library/2/books/

Retrieves all the books from the Library 2.

- **Using GET:**

> GET - api/library/2/books/3/5/10/33/...../pages

- **Using POST:**

> POST - api/library/2/books/pages

**Body:**

```
{
    "books_id": [
        2,
        30,
        40,
        20,
        30
    ]
}
```

I’m in a real doubt here between using **POST** or **GET** methods to implement that. Books Ids on URL will get really messy if there was like 100-200 books to retrieve. I want some enlightenment here.

I'm using PHP to handle the Rest Application and all those methods above are valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This operation matches the standard semantics of the [GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) method, and therefore the expectations of various software. For example:

- many HTTP clients know that they can automatically retry GET requests in case of errors
- it’s easier to cache responses to GET

If your book IDs are independent from library IDs, then it may be better to drop the reference to the library, and do just

```
GET /api/books/3,5,10,33/pages
```

> Books Ids on URL will get really messy if there was like 100-200 books to retrieve

If every book ID is 6 digits long, this adds up to just 700-1400 bytes. This is well within the range supported by any good HTTP client. To really push the practical limits on URL length, you would need many more books — but do you really need (or want) to support retrieval of so many pages at once?

(Alternatively, though, your book IDs might be much longer — perhaps UUIDs.)

If you do run into limits on URL length, it’s OK to use POST to a dedicated “endpoint”:

```
POST /api/books/bulk-pages

{"books_id": [3, 5, 10, 33]}
```

POST is defined in [RFC 7231 § 4.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) as a sort of “catch-all” method:

> process the
> representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's
> own specific semantics. For example, POST is used for the following
> functions (among others):
>
> o  Providing a block of data, such as the fields entered into an HTML
> form, to a data-handling process;

As a curiosity, there has been a recent attempt to [standardize a SEARCH method](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-snell-search-method-00) that would allow request payloads like POST, but also be [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) and [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2) like GET. Unfortunately, that effort has stalled, so you probably shouldn’t try to use SEARCH now.

Technically, the protocol allows you to send a payload even with a GET request, but as [RFC 7231 § 4.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) notes, this is unusual and may cause trouble:

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

Comment: You answer was very good and it was the closest I wanted.

I can't drop the Library Reference because of the possibility of having books with same Id's.

Whats the semantic difference between using commas or slash ? In your example you separate the books ids using commas, what would be the impact of using slashes ?

Comment: @IgorMorse In a URL path, slashes separate levels of hierarchy (like folders in a file system). This affects URL joining and normalization. Commas don’t have special meaning in a path, so you can use them as you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Your answer was the one that I was wishing for, thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 2):

### Query parameters

For retrieving multiple *books*, consider **query parameters** (using `?`):

```
GET /api/library/2/books?id=3,5,10,33
```

### Matrix parameters

For retrieving *pages* of multiple *books*, you could consider **matrix parameters** (using `;`):

```
GET /api/library/2/books;id=3,5,10,33/pages
```

Then you also can use **query parameters** to filter the pages.

---

<sup>• For more details about matrix and query parameters, refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2048121/1426227).</sup>

<sup>• Also refer to the following sections of the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) for more details: [§3.3 Path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) and [§3.4 Query](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)</sup>

Comment: This is the first time I'm seeing Matrix parameters. This could add some complexity to my EndPoint as I use Regular Expression to map the routes.

`GET - api/library/2/books/3/5/10/33/...../pages`

Using this as a variation would be considered wrong ?

Comment: @IgorMorse Once slashes represent hierarchy, it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

**POST** in your case does not look semantically correct. Maybe you can try query params like

> GET - api/library/2/books/pages?ids=[1,2,3,4,5]