# semicolon in the restful service URL truncate the characters after it

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, dropwizard, javax.ws.rs

I have the below code as my restful service operation.

```
    @GET
    @UnitOfWork
    @Timed(name = "get-requests")
    @Path("/{referenceId}")
    public Response get(@Auth @ApiParam(access = "internal") UserPrincipal user,
            @ApiParam(name = "id", value = "reference ID", required = true)
            @PathParam("referenceId") String id) {
         return Response.ok(id).build();
    }
```

However, I noticed if I pass in `m1234;5678`, I get only `m1234` returned. I tried `@Path("/{referenceId:.*}")`, but it doesn't work. 
I also tried use `@Encode` at the top of the method to make sure the url is not decoded and then try to replace `%3B` with ";" in the code. But it seems not working also.

Please note that I cannot use Spring framework. Thanks.

Comment: So , what framework / technology you are using ? jax-rs or others? Please add a tag of that technology to your questions

Comment: Have you tried all the way mentioned in [this](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/userguide/html/_Encoded_and_encoding.html) link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `;` denotes a **matrix parameter**. Use [`@MatrixParam`](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-matrixparam-example/) to get its value.

See also the answers to this question: [URL matrix parameters vs. request parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048121/url-matrix-parameters-vs-request-parameters)

**Edit:** The *key* of the matrix parameter would be `5678`, the value would be `null`.

There is a way to get achieve what you want by using [`PathSegment`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/PathSegment.html) as the *type* of the parameter instead of `String`:

```
@PathParam("referenceId) PathSegment id
```

In the body of the method, you can use

```
String idValue = id.getPath();
```

to get `m1234;5678`.

Comment: Thanks. Very detailed answer. Appreciate your help.