# How to read param from the url in angular

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular11

How can I get the value of param2 based on name in angular?

http://localhost:4200/home#parma1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3

Tried Below:

```
constructor(
private router: Router,
private route: ActivatedRoute) { }


ngOnInit(): void {
this.route.queryParams
  .subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params);    // Out put : {} 
  }
);
console.log(this.router.url); // Output : /home#parma1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

}

Is there any standard approach to get the parameters when parameters separated with `#` instead of `?` ?

Answer (score 1):

since `activatedRoute` doesn't recognize params if wasn't seperated by **`?`** based on your example. Just use the traditional [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

by this, you can get the value of `param2`

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams("http://localhost:4200/home#parma1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3");

const param2 = params.get("param2");
console.log(param2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You can follow the https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action

`this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => { this.name = params['name']; });`

Answer (score 0):

try to use **queryParamMap**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.route.queryParamMap
  .subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params);
  }
)
```

or use

```
let param1 = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('param1')
```

Comment: queryParamMap is returning empty so it is not working as expected.

snapshot not exist in route. Could you please confirm declaration of route ?

Comment: inject in the service : private route:ActivatedRoute

Answer (score 0):

Those after "#" called `fragment`, and the way to get it is

```
this.activatedRoute.fragment
  .subscribe(frgmt => {
    console.log(frgmt);    // Output (type string): parma1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3' 
  }
);
```

if you want `param` but don't want to use question mark, then use [`matrix`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048121/url-matrix-parameters-vs-query-parameters). Something like this: */app;param1=1;param2=2;param3=3*

Comment: This is returning empty result. Not working as expected.

Comment: share the code you write