# Sending variables to a webpage without using QueryString

Tags: asp.net

I have an application that can launch Internet Explorer to a specific website.  The problem is, if you include a question mark within the URL, it transforms it into %20;  For example, if I tell it to go to:  http://www.domain.com/default.aspx?id=572 when Internet Explorer opens, the webpage is changed to http://www.domain.com/default.aspx%20;id=572 and ASP.NET is unable to render the page when it looks like that.

I can't do anything to change the application, and as far as I can tell, there is no escape character.

Is there any other way I can pass a variable to ASP.NET other than with a QueryString from a third party application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

- Put the parameter into the path:

  - `http://www.domain.com/default.aspx/id=572`, or
  - `http://www.domain.com/default.aspx/572`, or
- (Ab)use [matrix parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401981/when-to-use-query-parameters-versus-matrix-parameters): `http://www.domain.com/default.aspx;id=572`

Either way you'll need to change the ASP.NET service to extract those parameter types.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually able to put the parameter into the path, and then use Request.Url.AbsolutePath to find out what the id was.