# Need to pass param as query/path but should not visible on URL

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I need pass a param from one route to other but it should not visible to user. I need it in Angular 6.

Comment: If it shouldn't be in the URL, you can't pass it as a query or path parameter.

Comment: you can use @Input decorater and pass the value through that variable.

Comment: You can hold the value in service.

Comment: I has variable from response and need to pass it to another ts  component to where it routes to next step and at the same time i don't want to view that variable on the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [matrix params](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40171609/9097714).

Then using the Angular [location](https://angular.io/api/common/Location), and [router](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events) services, to read and then overwrite the URL history.

It isn't elegant but works..and achieves what you asked.

**Example for the check and re-write of location history:**

```
this.router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
.subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
  const matrixParams = this.location.path().split(';');

  ... do something with the matrixParam

  if(matrixParams.length > 1) {
    this.location.replaceState(matrixParams[0])
  }

}));
```

**Other ideas (as mentioned)**:

- Use a service to pass the data around, check for it in OnInit
- As mentioned, pass it between components using @Input()

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the URL to change you can use `skipLocationChange` strategy.

https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras