# REST paired values in path param

Tags: rest

I would to know if it is possible to have a rest call with this format:

/{id1,id2}

So we end up with a pair of values id1 and id2. I know a hacky way to do it but I am asking if there is a official way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note quite clear what you are asking.

You shouldn't have a URI with that spelling, because '{' and '}' are not allowed in segments; see [RFC 3986, Appendix A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A)

But a [URI Template](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) with that spelling should be fine.  The trick is that you will need at least [level 3 template support](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-1.2)

Here's a [demo based on Handy-URI-Templates](http://www.utilities-online.info/uritemplate/?save=3da3b2f8-3a88-4c65-9e42-bc826ac97f46-uritemplate#.WXK5UemQy71)

REST, of course, doesn't care what spelling you use for your identifiers; as far as REST is concerned, an identifier is opaque; any information encoded into the identifier is done at the server's discretion and is reserved for its own use.

> I managed to do this by having the path like this: /{src},{dst}

You may want to investigate [matrix parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401981/when-to-use-query-parameters-versus-matrix-parameters).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I wanted to have two values passed through the REST API. I managed to do this by having the path like this:

/{src},{dst}