# How can I receive a get method in quarkus, in which the input parameter to be taken is in the url in the middle of it

Tags: java, get, quarkus

Good afternoon.

I am currently working with an API of the GET type in which we must use the following url for the get method as standard:

/users/{user_id}/customers

The question here is that I don't know how I can get this value, if I can only use RequestMapping and if so, my user_id input parameter is a combination of the Query Parameters type like the following example:

/users/**user_id?id=1&value=12345678**/customers

That is, can I retrieve the query parameters from the user_id field as indicated in the example url or can this only apply the query parameters to the end of the URL?

Answer (score 0):

There is an *RFC* for the *Uniform Resource Locators*, which defines a form.
*[RFC 1738 - Uniform Resource Locators (URL) – Section 5 – BNF for specific URL schemes](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738#section-5)*.

The *[BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)* for *httpurl* is defined as follows.

```
httpurl        = "http://" hostport [ "/" hpath [ "?" search ]]
hostport       = host [ ":" port ]
hpath          = hsegment *[ "/" hsegment ]
hsegment       = *[ uchar | ";" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" ]
search         = *[ uchar | ";" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" ]

uchar          = unreserved | escape
unreserved     = alpha | digit | safe | extra
escape         = "%" hex hex
safe           = "$" | "-" | "_" | "." | "+"
extra          = "!" | "*" | "'" | "(" | ")" | ","
```

> *"... can I retrieve the query parameters from the user_id field as indicated in the example url or can this only apply the query parameters to the end of the URL?"*

It would appear that you would, most likely, not be able to utilize that form.
The parameters would be part of the *hsegment* field, which does not typically allow for a *?* character.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the syntax you may want to use is not supported (or you have to encode/decode data by youself), but what about using [matrix param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401981/when-to-use-query-parameters-versus-matrix-parameters?rq=3)?

`/users/user_id;id=1;value=12345678/customers`